# Error SQL04111: Visual studio 2010 database project

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a relation in my tables in visual studio 2010 database project and I am getting this error:

```
Error SQL04111: The referenced table '[dbo].[tblAccount]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.
```

Here is the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblDispute]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AccountNo] 
    FOREIGN KEY (AccountNo)
    REFERENCES tblAccount ([Account No])  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I fixed the issue by adding the other column from account table. Account table has two column primary/composite key and in dispute table I was adding only one of the two tables.